# Simulate Paypal html button POST request in php

Tags: php, curl, nginx, paypal

i want to send POST request to paypal in php which simulate Pay Now html button, what happen is i POST [standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_buy_now/#a-basic-buy-now-button) html form to php file on my live server(nginx) , add some [Variable](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) and send the POST request ,i am expecting the user redirect to paypal website but i get blank page with no error

```
 <?php
// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'test@me.com';
$return_url = 'https://example.com/payment-successful.html';
$cancel_url = 'https://example.com/payment-cancelled.html';
$notify_url = 'https://example.com/payments.php';

$item_name = 'Test Item';
$item_amount = 10.00;


$querystring = '';
$querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&"; 
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
}
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

// POST data to paypal 
$ch =curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $querystring);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a variable to your curl_exec call and do a var_dump on this variable to see what is going on.  The blank page sounds about right.

If you are still having an issue with this post the results of the curl_exec and we'll figure it out from there.